# TightVNC to an Ubuntu desktop on EC2:  the letter d doesn't appear when typed in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vnc

I followed [this article](http://bitnami.org/article/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-ec2-ebs) and I have the desktop running on Ubuntu on an EC2 instance and I can connect to it from TightVNC.  When I try to use Terminal, when I type certain characters, they seems to get lost.  For example, I can type **passw**  but the when I try to type **d** that character doesn't appear.  If I then press Enter, the Terminal window minimizes.  I can't type the character d at all.  All other letters & numbers are fine.  How can I fix this?

BTW, I'm using Bash in Terminal.  Everything works when I SSH into the instance using PuTTY.  It's only when I use a Terminal instance from TightVNC that this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly and answer but VNC is a mess. I suggest you migrate to NX. Its faster and uses ssh by default. I use FreeNX on Ubuntu on EC2.

edit: I was able to replicate this bug.

Possible solutions:

http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/howto-ubuntu-vnc-encoding-server/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10608/d-key-on-vnc-viewer-minimises-all-windows

Comment: I tried a couple of tutorials (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX, http://aws-musings.com/4-easy-steps-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-your-ubuntu-ec2-instance/, ) to get NX installed on my Ubuntu instance but no luck.  If you have any pointers, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Can you type an upper-case "D"? Are you using Bash? Try this:

Type the following, but don't press Enter:

```
binD '"D":self-insert'
```

Now move your cursor to each capital "D" and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> (that's lower-case ell) or <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> to change the "D" to "d". Once you've done both, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>.

Now type this command and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>:

```
bind '"\C-m": accept-line'
```

Next, check your `~/.inputrc` file for invalid key bindings (they won't have the `bind` command or the outermost quotes). You should also check your shell startup files for invalid `bind` commands.

Comment: I was able to enter binD '"D":self-insert' with the lowercase d.  But I couldn't enter the second command because lower case d still doesn't work.  When I tried to type the d in bind, the Terminal window would minimize.  So it looks like the first bind command didn't work. Yes I'm using Bash.

Comment: @Sajee: Try `xmodmap -pke | less` and see if there's anything odd about "d" or "Return". You may have to use the Alt-l trick to get the "d" in "xmodmap" and you may need to use Ctrl-j to enter the command. It may also work better to redirect the output to a file so you can come back and view it in an SSH session.

Comment: @Dennis: the results of the xmodmap shows this for d: "keycode  40 = d D" and for Return: "keycode  36 = Return".  Does this look right?

Comment: @Sajee: It's the same for me (at least through SSH and PuTTY). Do you get the same results for both VNC and PuTTY? There's somewhere you've got a keymapping out of whack and at the moment I'm drawing a blank where else to look. Try running `xev` and press some keys and see what it shows.

Comment: @Dennis: pressing d in xev causes the Terminal and xev windows to mimimize.

Comment: @Sajee: When you restore the `xev` window is there any indication of what it saw?

Comment: @Dennis:  I pressed an 'a' which generated  KeyPress/KeyRelease events.  I then clicked 'd' which didn't generate a KeyPress/KeyRelease pair, rather there is a couple of FocusOut events, Leave Notify, UnmapNotify and three PropertyNotify.  I'm how which these events were generated by pressing 'd' and which were generated by me restoring the minimized Terminal windows to see the output.

Comment: @Sajee: As I indicated earlier, I'm drawing a blank for what to do next. Sorry. I'm assuming you've already restarted everything to eliminate some temporary condition as the cause.